# Angular fortify scan(typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, fortify

do we exclude the dist and node_modules folder when we do fortify scan for typescript angular project.
I see a lot errors from node_modules and dist folder.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not benefit from running static analysis on code that does not belong to your codebase e.g. running it on `node_modules`. Edit: You should though have a mechanism in place to check dependencies for security issues.

Also `dist` files do not fill the purpose of complying with code quality rules, as they are optimized for execution.

If you work at a company with a specification on this matter, I would consult that. Otherwise leave the mentioned folders out.